# c# RichTextBox display getting slow as many lines

Tags: c#, richtextbox, syslog

I am using RichTextBox as syslog display.
It is displaying more than thousands and getting too slow to make application not handle window event in time.
Is there any better way to use syslog output without such big impact application performance?

Visual Studio Output looks not big impact performance even lots lines.
Hope someone else can guide me to use better syslog.

Thank you.

Comment: You are getting slow experience after loading data in RTB or taking time to load content in RTB?

Comment: Might not be the best choice of a control.  Perhaps consider a _virtual_ `ListView`?

Comment: Show relevant code!